# How to upgrade xrandr in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, vnc, xrandr

While trying to change resolution in VNC using:

```
xrandr --fb 1440x900
```

I get the following error:

```
 xrandr: Server RandR version before 1.2
```

trying to "apt-get" it, the result suggests to install x11-xserver-utils. However, when I run "apt-get" for x11-xserver-utils, it results with:

```
x11-xserver-utils is already the newest version.
```

So any idea on how to upgrade xrandr to 1.2 or later?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is not due to the xrandr program being too old. I suppose it's the X server that does not support xrandr extension.

Comment: Any update on this?

my ubuntu now seems to be running xrandr 1.4, but I was hoping to upgrade it to 1.5